# Lifetime of clothes moths

Tags: pest-control, lifespan

*Cross-posting, as I'm not at all sure which StackExchange this belongs in. Very happy to move / delete where I've chosen poorly, and a better SE can be recommended.*

---

Question:

**Can anyone advise on how long clothes moths eggs can last unhatched, and how long the larvae would then be able to survive *without any natural fibre food.***

---

I'm currently trying to deal with a clothes moth infestation, and your site has been invaluable.
Are you able to advise how long the larvae can survive without any available food?

We've removed the carpet and soft-furnishings from a room, and thoroughly hoovered, but there are nooks and crannys (especially around the skirting boards), which I suspect still have eggs in. I've thoroughly removed any fibres left from the carpet, so my plan is to leave the room for 10 days to ensure any remaining live eggs have hatched into larvae (which then have nothing to eat, and then ... X? ... days to ensure that those larvae have all died.

Are you able to advise what X should be?

We're under the impression that the larvae can ONLY eat natural fibres, so they can't eat, e.g. artificial foam underlay or cardboard boxes & books. Even if those are the only things around them, they can't consume those and will thus starve.

Comment: If you are dealing with a real clothes moth, your natural _plant_ fibers should be safe, they can digest only keratin, which translates to hair and feathers.